# C# public static dictionary

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary

So I'm trying to make a publicly accessible dictionary for my entire program to access, I created that under my Form as such:

```
public static Dictionary<string, int> categories = new Dictionary<string, int>
    {
    {"services", 0},
    {"files", 0},
    {"shortcuts", 0},
    {"registry", 0},
    {"browsers", 0}
    };
```

Now, inside of a private method, I have this code:

```
                foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> reference in categories)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < scanLines.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (scanLines[i].Contains(reference.Key))
                    {
                        start = i + 1;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                for (int i = start; i < scanLines.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (scanLines[i].Contains("*"))
                    {
                        stop = i - 1;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                // Write the result for the category by subtracting the difference between
                // the start and stop variables
                categories[reference.Key] = stop - start;
```

This is basically breaking up a log file in sections to count the lines in between those sections declared in the category dictionary. Now my problem is the line of code

```
categories[reference.Key] = stop - start;
```

keeps throwing an Invalid Operation Exception Error. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot change collection (and `Dictionary` is collection too) inside `foreach` loop for it. You can do quick workaround by creating duplicate collection as follows:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> reference in categories.ToList())
```

Comment: I did try this, and even tried using .ToArray() as well... but it gives me the same result for each category item. The sample log I am reading from has 6 results under just one of those categories, all the others should be 0, but it returns 5 for all of them. Obviously I need to work this within a for loop instead of a foreach loop. I just can't figure out how to do that.

Comment: @user2613018 The original question is about exception. Do you get exception in case of `.ToList` or `.ToArray`?

Comment: Yes you have a valid point, it did address the Exception I was getting, as I do not get any with the .ToList() method. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You try to change csope-closed varible (categories) in foreach loop. It is unavalible operation.

It is simply to understand, as if you are allowed to change varible can be stored in out-of-memory stack.

Use anouther varible, as example, to make this operation.